# JSTL tags don't see java variables

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

There is some JSP page and List:

```
List<Articles> listArticles = ListArticles.getArticles(1);
Iterator<Articles> iter = listArticles.iterator();
```

and then I iterate through this list and I add its elements to ArrayList

```
<%
    ArrayList<String> arts = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Articles currentArticle = iter.next();
        arts.add(currentArticle.getTitle());
    }
%>
```

and then I try print this ArrayList, but nothing happens (c:forEach simply don't see "${arts}")

```
 <c:forEach var="listItem" items="${arts}">
       c:out value="${listItem}" />
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Also you may wanna avoid using scriplets  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `arts` to the page context. JSTL tags don't know about page level JSP variables, it works with the JSP scopes.

Add this after you populate your `arts` array

```
pageContext.setAttribute("arts", arts);
```

and you should be fine.